# Middle Mouse Button Paste not working Ubuntu - Logitech G602 wireless mouse

Tags: 20.04, mouse

After installing Ubuntu 20, I am unable to use my middle mouse button to paste. I can still scroll using the wheel, but clicking the middle mouse button doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to restore middle-click functionality by switching the G602's power-consumption switch up and down.

[image: mouse picture]

Comment: You saved my day !